# Docker registry 2.0 api v2 access using auth token

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have private docker repository in quay.io and I want to get list of repositories and tags related to it. 
So I use curl -IL https://quay.io/user/accountName/v2/_catalog 
it returns
HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED
Server: nginx/1.9.5
Date: Thu, 18 Feb 2016 11:02:19 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 117
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: So what is the question? can you explain more?

Comment: I want list of repositories from quay.io account using v2 api
According to api document https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/
it should return list but in my case it give authentication error without any realm url to get auth token

Comment: Plz check Listing Repositories section of docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api